# I want to make an element clickable again

Tags: jquery

i have a little problem with jquery.
That is my code:

```
   $("#amis_commun_liste .afficher_plus_modal").bind('click',function f(){
    var afficher_plus_modal = $(this).attr("class");
    var id = "<?php  echo $_GET['id']; ?>";


    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      dataType: "html", 
      url: "voir_profil_includes/func_infos.php",
      data: {
        "afficher_plus_modal": afficher_plus_modal,
        "id" : id           
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#amis_commun_liste .afficher_plus_modal").html("En cours");
      },
      success: function(html) {

      $("#add").html(html);


      }
    });
  });
```

I want to make  element  $("#amis_commun_liste .afficher_plus_modal") clickable again

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not clickable"?

Comment: It is not clickable. I want to make it clickable again.

Comment: What action makes or when does it become unclickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind is deprecated try to use "ON" method

```
$("#amis_commun_liste .afficher_plus_modal").on('click',function f(){
var afficher_plus_modal = $(this).attr("class");
var id = "<?php  echo $_GET['id']; ?>";


$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  dataType: "html", 
  url: "voir_profil_includes/func_infos.php",
  data: {
    "afficher_plus_modal": afficher_plus_modal,
    "id" : id           
  },
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#amis_commun_liste .afficher_plus_modal").html("En cours");
  },
  success: function(html) {

  $("#add").html(html);


  }
});
});
```